# Issues in android contacts when convert to json array in android

Tags: android, json, contacts

Currently i am working with android contacts,i want to convert this in to json array for post this contacts to webserver,i am able to get all contacts,but issues is when i print the json array it shows only the last contact.i think the object value is not retained ,how can i solve this issue?i just post my code below.

```
        JSONArray jsnConts=new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsnMain= new JSONObject();
        ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        lengthh=cursor.getCount();

        JSONObject a[]=new JSONObject[lengthh];
        ArrayList<String>cnt2=new ArrayList<String>();
        contactarray=new String[lengthh][avalues.length];

        System.out.println(cursor.getCount());

        JSONObject jsnName=new JSONObject ();
        int kk=0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
        {

        ArrayList<String>cnt1=new ArrayList<String>();
            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));       
            id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            mail(id);
            Ph_num(id);

               for (int i=0; i<4; i++) 
            { 
                if(i==0)
                {
                    cnt1.add("Name ="+displayName);
                    jsnName.put("Name", displayName);
                }
                if(i==1)
                {
                    cnt1.add("id ="+id);
                    jsnName.put("id", id);
                }
                if(i==2)
                {
                    cnt1.add("email ="+email_data);
                    jsnName.put("email", EMAIL);
                    jsnName.put("email1", EMAIL1);
                    jsnName.put("email2", EMAIL2);
                }
                if(i==3)
                {
                    cnt1.add("PHONE_NUM_DATA ="+PHONE_NUM_DATA);
                    jsnName.put("ph1", PH_NUM);
                    jsnName.put("ph2", PH_NUM1);
                    jsnName.put("ph3", PH_NUM2);
                    jsnName.put("ph4", PH_NUM3);

                }
// jsnConts.put(jsnName);
//jsnConts.put(kk, jsnName);

            }
            cnt2.addAll(cnt1);

//   System.out.println("test"+jsnName);
            jsnConts.put(jsnName);
//   jsnConts.put(kk, jsnName);
            kk++;

        }
        System.out.println("test"+jsnName);
        System.out.println("testjsn"+jsnConts);
// System.out.println("------"+a);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't printing a JSONArray, you're printing the variable jsnName, which is a JSONObject-  a single value.  And you're overwriting it each time through the loop.  YOu need to create a new JSONObject each time through the loop, add each completed JSONObject to a JSONArray, and print that.

Comment: thanks for the answer.what a stupid mistake i made,thanks for pointing out.